# Executing shell-script with parameters from java

Tags: java, bash, runtime

I have been googling for some time, and everyone seems to have a different solution, none of which appear to be working for me.

I have tried both `ProcessBuilder` and `Runtime`. Both calling the `.sh` file directly and feeding it to `/bin/bash`. With no luck.

Back to basics, my current code is as follows;

```
String cmd[] = { "~/path/to/shellscript.sh", "foo", "bar" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Which is giving a `No such file or directory` error, despite that manually running;

```
~/path/to/shellscript.sh foo bar
```

Works perfectly from bash.

I need to keep the `~` because this shellscript exists in slightly different forms for three different users.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option is to handle `~` yourself:

```
String homeDir = System.getenv("HOME");
String[] cmd = { homeDir + "/path/to/shellscript.sh", "foo", "bar" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Another is to let Bash handle it for you:

```
String[] cmd = { "bash", "-c", "~/path/to/shellscript.sh foo bar" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Ah, is the `~` likely to be causing the problems do you think? Does java not know how to pass such a path to the system call?

Comment: Yes, most likely ~ is the reason. You can have the above suggestion if per user the script is in the same relative path in the home directory, or have the path configured per user , as I suggested.

Comment: @lynks: Yes. Tilde-expansion is a feature of Bash — see [§3.5.2 "Tilde Expansion" in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion) — and not something that Java knows anything about. (And not anything that the system knows anything about, either.)

Comment: The second suggestion worked perfectly, thanks. I didn't even think to check for the `~`

Comment: what if i want to run shell script with sudo user ?

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, tilde is a shell-specific expansion which should be handled manually by replacing it with the home directory of the current user (e.g with `$HOME` if defined).

Besides the solutions already given, you might also consider using [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) and [commons-exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) from the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) project:

```
...
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.Executor;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
...
CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine("path/to/shellscript.sh");
cmd.addArgument("foo");
cmd.addArgument("bar");

Executor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.setWorkingDirectory(FileUtils.getUserDirectory());
exec.execute(cmd);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would recommend that you use the [ScriptEngine](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/RunningScriptswithJavaScriptEngine.htm) instead of System.getRuntime().exec 
I think it will make things more easy for you. 
Bare in mind you need for this JDK 6 and above. 
In addition, regarding your specific problem - I really think that this issue should be configurable. 
You can do the following: 
A. Have in your .bash_rc or .bash_profile (for each user) define a path to the configuration 
script using: 
EXPORT MY_SCRIPT= 
B. Read this value from java code, using  
`String sciprtPath  = System.getenv("MY_SCRIPT")` to get the value. 
C. Run the script , the way you did in your code, with scriptPath variable, or using the scriptEngine.