# execute pig command in Java program

Tags: java, process, apache-pig, runtime.exec

I used to write PHP code to execute pig command, it worked well,
Now I switch to Java but seems it won't work, here is my code:

```
String pigCommand = "pig -x local -p ouput=/tmp my_pig_script.pig";

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p;
int exitVal;

try {
    p = r.exec(pigCommand);
    exitVal = p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();

    System.out.println("exitVal: " + exitVal);
    System.out.println("Done");
```

If I run the that pig command in console directly, it works, if I replace
that Pig command with other shell command say 'ping www.yahoo.com', and run the
java Program, it works too. So what might be the problem? thanks

Comment: Any error messages.  What does it do or say when you run it?

Comment: 1) Consume the error stream & implement all the other tips in the Java World article linked from the [Runtime.exec tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).  2) Use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the `Process`. 3) For greater robustness, break the `String pigCommand` into `String[] pigCommands`. 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Specifically to run pig script, it is better to run it through `PigServer` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152068/run-pig-in-java-without-embedding-pig-script)

Comment: Just a guess: does the pig command rely on environment specific info (something à la JAVA_HOME, but for pig)? Is the path correct?

Comment: I'd also suggest to use `PigServer` as Raze2dust suggested. Alternatively you might also use `Commons-exec`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13185617/1050422

Comment: Another vote for using `PigServer`.

Comment: switched to PigServer, it surely solved the problem.

Comment: @Raze2dust Would you write an answer from your comment?

Comment: @fglez Done, I hope it is more helpful this way.

Comment: @user468587 Could you accept Raze2dust answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`PigServer`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/PigServer.html) to execute pig scripts from java programs. It is more foolproof and more portable.

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299259/373151